# What is the physical significance of the damping function in calculation of vdW interaction energy?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, density-functional-theory, dispersion-correction

In order to take care for the singularity (also removing the double counting of exchange-correlation) obtained with this expression,
$$E_\mathrm{vdW} = \frac{C^6}{R^6}$$

many type of damping functions are utilized. Such as,

$$E_\mathrm{vdW} = \frac{C^6}{R^6} \cdot f_\mathrm{famp}(r)$$

One such damping function is, (Grimme type, Fermi function)

$$f_\mathrm{damp}(r) = \frac{s_6}{1+\exp\left[ -B\left(\frac{r^{AB}}{s_r R^{AB}_\mathrm{vdW}}\right)\right]}$$

when, $r$ = interatomic distance, $R^{AB}_\mathrm{vdW}$ or (R) is summation of vdW radius of two atoms $s_6$ and $s_r$ are two parameters.
$s_6$ depend upon the XC functional and $s_r$ is another scaling factor.
$B$ is the exponent.

Literature$^{[1]}$ suggests that value for $B$ is found by setting $f_\mathrm{damp} = 0.99$ when $r = 1.2 \cdot R$.

Also, the value of these parameters can also be found from [here](https://www.chemie.uni-bonn.de/pctc/mulliken-center/software/dft-d3/functionals).

To my knowledge, these values are optimized for each functional.
Is there any physical meaning to these values of the parameters?
Actually, I am more interested in the $s_r$ value and if this has any physical significance...

[1] J Chem Phys, 116, 515(2002)